# Obligated to return to a non-Jew what was stolen by accident?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, gezel-stealing, intent-accident-purposely, lost-and-found

After renting a place from a non-Jew, I realized I left with a small object accidentally. Am I obligated to return it as a "stolen" object, or is it considered a "lost" object that I am not obligated (and possibly forbidden) to return?

Comment: As a reminder, this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends and consult your rabbi for a practical ruling.

Comment: Slightly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33246/15256

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48039/759

Answer (score 1):

One classical halachic case is one of accidentally switching items (from [here](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/one-who-accidently-switched-an-item-with-another-person/))

> One who [accidentally] took the wrong item while at the house of a
>   mourner or while participating in a festive meal, may not use the item
>   [that he accidentally took] and **doing so is considered stealing.**

Regarding the object being possibly forbidden to be returned to non-Jews, it is true the concern exists in some cases (see sources [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/86776/11501)) but note the Rambam ([Gezelah va'Avedah 11:3](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1088895/jewish/Gezelah-vaAvedah-Chapter-Eleven.htm)) who writes (regarding a found object, not something you took by mistake)

> if one returns to sanctify God's name, so that others will praise the
>   Jewish people and know that they are trustworthy, this is
>   praiseworthy.

The Rambam's language regarding stealing from a gentile is much stronger ([Gezelah va'Avedah 1:2](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1088885/jewish/Gezelah-vaAvedah-Chapter-One.htm))

> It is forbidden to rob even the slightest amount.
>   It is forbidden even to rob or to withhold money from a gentile who
>   worships idols. If one robs or withholds money from such a person, one
>   must return it.

Regarding the combination of stealing by accident (which is addressed in *halacha*) and doing so from a non-Jew (which is not - the classical case is whether to return a lost object), I would argue that no one would think it is OK to take things accidentally from non-Jews and not return them. And argue that, if the Rambam writes one should return a lost object if it is a kiddush Hashem, it is an even stronger recommendation if one accidentally took something from them!

---

Therefore I believe that, in the spirit of [Dvarim 6:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.6.18?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) "Do what is right and good in the sight of the Lord", the right thing to do would be to call the person and ask

1. whether he/she wants the object back? or
2. whether you can reimburse him/her for it? or
3. whether the object is insignificant to him/her?

---

See also the story of [Shimon ben Shetach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simeon_ben_Shetach#Fairness) from Yerushalmi [Bava Metzia 2:5](http://mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r4202.htm), as well as [here](https://www.torahmusings.com/2015/06/stealing-by-accident/) from R Daniel Mann ("of course, he has to return it when he finds out the truth"), [here](http://dafyomi.co.il/discuss_daf.php?gid=21&sid=20&daf=113&n=2) regarding the definition of an *akum* vs. today's non-Jews, [here](http://www.angelfire.com/mt/talmud/theft.html) for further halachic sources and [here](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/1203-returning-stolen-object/).

And as usual, [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn from MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).

Comment: I think @DoubleAA's link points to the right direction - it is a clear unintentional steal.

Comment: I meant that question had the right sources from Shu"A 348,2.

Comment: @AlBerko but here it is the Jew who makes a mistake - and isn't there a real risk of *hilul Hashem* when the non-Jew realizes his Jewish renter left with an object ?!

Comment: Did you read my comment on the question? Would you call it a mistake? The act of "actively taking" is called גזילה in any way, either intentionally or unintentionally. Mildly rephrasing the question does not help to lessen its severity, I think.

Comment: @AlBerko I saw your comment on the question now - and agree